# Can't connect my containered Spring Boot Application to my local MySQL datasource

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have this application in Spring Boot with two datasources (MySql and Oracle). The Oracle one is in a server, I'm having no problems with it, but the Mysql is local, my application searchs data in it then compares with the Oracle one.

All is fine until I try to put the application on a Docker container, it doesn't connect to my Mysql, I've tried tons os suggestions on the internet and none worked. I need some help this is my latest try...

My .properties

```
## ===============================
## = MySQL
## ===============================
spring.datasource.mysql.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.mysql.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST}:3306/routerServer
spring.datasource.mysql.username=user
spring.datasource.mysql.password=pwd
```

My Datasource conf.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "mysqlEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "mysqlTransactionManager",
        basePackages = { "my_api.mysql" })
public class MySQLDatasourceConfig {

    @Bean(name="mysqlProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.mysql")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {

        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name="mysqlDatasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.mysql")
    public DataSource datasource(@Qualifier("mysqlProperties") DataSourceProperties properties){

        return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean(name="mysqlEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean
            (EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
             @Qualifier("mysqlDatasource") DataSource dataSource){

        HashMap<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .properties(props)
                .packages("my_api.mysql.*")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "mysqlTransactionManager")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.jpa")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("mysqlEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {

        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  my-api:
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
      - MYSQL_HOST=${MYSQL_HOST}
      - ORACLE_HOST=${ORACLE_HOST}
    build: 
      context: ./my-api
      args:
        - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
        - APP_JAR=${APP_JAR}
      dockerfile: my-api.dockerfile
    image: img/my-api-${APP_ENV}
    container_name: my-api-${APP_ENV}
    ports:
      - ${BACKEND_APP_PORT}:${BACKEND_APP_PORT}
```

My .env file

```
APP_JAR="my-api"
APP_ENV="dsv"
BACKEND_APP_PORT=8080
MYSQL_HOST="127.0.0.1"
```

When I run docker-compose up I get this exception

```
my-api-dsv  | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
my-api-dsv  |
my-api-dsv  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:815) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:438) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:189) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar!/:2.7.8]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar!/:2.7.8]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar!/:2.7.8]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar!/:2.7.8]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar!/:2.7.8]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar!/:2.7.8]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.my_api.MyApiApplication.main(MyApiApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
my-api-dsv  |     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[java-app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[java-app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[java-app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[java-app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
my-api-dsv  | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
my-api-dsv  |
my-api-dsv  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
my-api-dsv  |     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:104) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:149) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:165) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:88) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:935) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:805) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     ... 57 more
my-api-dsv  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
my-api-dsv  |     at sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:669) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:645) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:62) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:935) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:805) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     ... 57 more
my-api-dsv  |
my-api-dsv  | 2023-11-28 14:08:06.842  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
my-api-dsv  |
my-api-dsv  | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
my-api-dsv  |
my-api-dsv  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:815) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:438) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:189) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar!/:5.6.14.Final]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar!/:2.7.8]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar!/:2.7.8]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar!/:2.7.8]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar!/:2.7.8]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar!/:2.7.8]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar!/:2.7.8]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.my_api.MyApiApplication.main(MyApiApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
my-api-dsv  |     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[java-app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[java-app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[java-app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
my-api-dsv  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[java-app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
my-api-dsv  | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
my-api-dsv  |
my-api-dsv  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
my-api-dsv  |     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:104) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:149) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:165) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:88) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:935) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:805) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     ... 57 more
my-api-dsv  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
my-api-dsv  |     at sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:669) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:645) ~[?:?]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:62) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:935) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:805) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
my-api-dsv  |     ... 57 more
```

I also tried the suggestion of adding `network_mode: "host"` to my docker-compose.yml but nothing changed, same exception

Comment: Try updating your .properties file like this >>

spring.datasource.mysql.url=jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/routerServer